# Cross-server schema comparison error

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two servers with databases schemas I want to compare: `DEV` and `TEST`. As far as I'm aware, they're both running SQL Server 2008. I've worked up this script to do so:

```
SELECT 
  h.name AS object_name 
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(h.schema_id) AS schema_name
  ,h.type_desc
  ,h.create_date
  ,h.modify_date
  ,td.create_date as 'First Pushed Date'
  ,td.modify_date as 'Last Pushed Date'
FROM 
   DEV.dev_dashboard.sys.objects h
left join 
   TEST.dashboard.sys.objects td on h.name = td.name
WHERE 
   td.modify_date < h.modify_date and 
   h.modify_date > '4/1/2014'
ORDER BY 
   td.modify_date DESC;
```

This script works perfectly fine for me most of the time, but certain combinations of databases produce an error:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "TEST" does not contain the table ""dashboard"."sys"."objects"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

This is greatly puzzling me, because there seems to be no rhyme or reason to it. If I'm connected to `DEV`, it complains about `TEST`. If I'm connected to `TEST` (using the same credentials), it complains about `DEV`. If I use the `DEV.dev_Dashboard` database (which should match `DEV.Dashboard`) with `TEST.Dashboard`, I get no errors if I'm connected to `DEV`, but I do if I'm connected to `TEST`.

I can't figure out a pattern, the databases and tables clearly exist, and I have full permission to everything (via Windows credentials). Why is this so inconsistent?

Comment: Well that's very ingenious of you, but you might find it easier to use a tool, for example, the SQL Server Data Tools which are a) free, and b) do all this schema/data comparison stuff for you/

Comment: @podiluska - Are there relevant tools other than tablediff?  That one doesn't do stored procedures, and doesn't check everything at once.

Comment: SSDT does all objects in the database, all at once, and can do data as well.

Comment: @podiluska - I'll check them out.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a Two-Hop Rule problem.  To test this, first login to one of the Windows Servers (DEV or TEST), then from there connect to the SQL Server running on the same box and attempt the query again.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Sorry for taking so long to follow up, but I tried this last night and it didn't work any differently from either of those servers.